# Repository Methods From Entity In ArrayCollection

Tags: php, symfony, repository, entity, arraycollection

So, we have two entities. One with repository and another is not. When we trying to get the data from another table we will get the ArrayCollection data. Question is how to call this entity repository methods? Is it real?

Example:

```
    $system = $this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getEntityManager()
            ->getRepository('SomeBundle:FirstEntity')
            ->findOneByColumnID($id);

    $den = $system->getDataFromSecondTable(); // ArrayCollection of SecondEntity
```

And then i want to use some kind of:

```
    $den[0]->functionFromSecondEntityRepository();
```

So, method "functionFromSecondEntityRepository" is in Repository of class SecondEntity and i can't call it - error on undefined method call "functionFromSecondEntityRepository".

So how can i do it in right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt provide too many details so I will make some example up here.

Let's say you have an Entity `FriendsList` and a [`One-to-Many`](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html) relationship with Entity `Friend`.

```
$List = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getEntityManager()
                ->getRepository('SomeBundle:FriendsList')
                ->find($id);

// The list you pulled in by ID can now be used
$List->getId();

foreach($List->getFriends() as $Friend)
{
    // Each friend will be output here, you have access
    // to the Friend methods now for each.
    $Friend->getId();
    $Friend->getFirstName();
    $Friend->getLastName();
    $Friend->getDOB();
    $Friend->getFavoriteColor();
}
```

By default when you create relationships a method to acquire the collection is created, in this example `getFriends` which returns an array of Entities. After you generate the entities look at your Entity Model to see which methods are available. By default one is created for each property in your entity and additional ones for Collections.

```
SomeCool/Bundle/Entity/FriendsList
Somecool/Bundle/Entity/Friend
```

The following is what a one-to-many relationship would look like if you use YAML configuration.

```
SomeCool\Bundle\Entity\FriendsList:
  type: entity
  table: null
  oneToMany:
    friend:
      targetEntity: Friend
      mappedBy: friendslist
      cascade:  ["persist"]

SomeCool/Bundle/Entity/Friend
  manytoOne:
    friends:
      targetEntity: FriendsList
      mappedBy: friend
      cascade:  ["persist"]
```

---

**Accessing a Repository**

**YAML Configuration (services.yml)**

```
somebundle.bundle.model.friends:
    class: SomeBundle/Bundle/Model/Friends
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

**On the Controller**

```
$friendsModel = $this->get('somebundle.bundle.model.friends');
$Friends = $friendsModel->findByFirstName('Bobby');

foreach($Friends as $Friend)
{
    $Friend->getLastName();
}
```

Comment: `$List->getFriends()` gets you an array of Friends, which each have their own methods. See my `foreach` example.

Comment: $List->getFriends() return ArrayCollection of FriendEntity, without their FriendEntityRepository methods, am i wrong? i can't call them :( (that's why i'm asking)

Comment: try in your foreach type echo get_class($Friend) you will see name of FriendEntity - not the FriendEntityRepository...

Comment: If you have an Entity relationship, they will have there methods. The Entity Manager automagically adds in your methods for each friend in the collection when `getFriends()` is called. If that's not working, you might not have the relationship configured properly. In Doctrine when you store a collection you are storing (essentially) an entire entity of `Friend` for each friend in the collection inside your `FriendsList`, therefore you have access to its `public` methods.

Comment: Ahh! I think I see what your trying to do. You're trying to access your Friends Model... I'll edit my answer and add that, I hope it helps.

Comment: yep, i know but now we talking about repository methods of entities, not the Entity methods, Entity methods work fine

Comment: @user1954544 Okay. It's there, see how I created service for the repository and accessed it through the service container. This is included in your controller by default, so that's the basis of the example.

Comment: so i can get it only by services?

Comment: @user1954544 Yes. The Entity Manager has to be injected. That's why its a service. Also, other things like Validation Classes and other models can be injected too.

Comment: btw, can we create "general" service that will load any repository we need for any entity we've got? or we have to write it for every entity separately?

Comment: AFAIK, you need to create a service for each.

Comment: what will you suggest if i have about 30+ entities with their own repository and they can be changed in any time we need, i think i'll die doing this services LOL

i think better way to create some controller that will compose me object i need by single entities without any relationship...

Comment: @user1954544 I would create a model, invoke all of your models (by a request method) and inject the necessary services into the container. That way you only need 1 code. But there is not an automated way to do it. Either way it's going to be some code.

Answer (score 0):

Repository methods are not available in Entities.  You would need a function in your AnotherEntity to grab the ArrayCollection.  IE:

```
class FirstEntity {

   public function getAnotherEntity()
   {
       return $this->anotherEntity;
   }

}

class AnotherEntity 
{
   public function getArrayCollection()
   {
       return $this->myArrayCollection;
   }
}

$firstEntity->getAnotherEntity()->getArrayCollection();
```

Another option would be to get the AnotherEntity's repository based on results from first:

```
$system = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getEntityManager()
        ->getRepository('SomeBundle:SomeEntity')
        ->findOneByColumnID($id);

$anotherEntity = $system->getAnotherEntity();

$anotherEntityResult = $this->getDoctrine()
                            ->getRepository(get_class($anotherEntity))
                            ->functionFromAnotherEntityRepository($anotherEntity->getId());
```

If using the second solution, I'd make sure that $anotherEntity is not null before attempting to retrieve the repository.

Comment: second one i understood, and yes it's seems to be way out

Comment: can you describe more first example ?

Comment: I'd need to see your entities to describe more / give you a better example.  Is the ArrayCollection you are retrieving based on a one-to-many or many-to many relationship?

Comment: will take your example FirstEntity is OneToMany and Another is ManyToOne

Comment: i'm thinking about second example...
will it be proper one? because we will create one entity twice, first it will be created in call $system->getAnotherEntity() and the second, we create it by our own (to get its repository)
what you think about this?